# How to put a carriage return back into an XML document?

Tags: python, xml, text, character-encoding

I'm trying to implement some python code for a colleague. My script uses an XML parser to parse over their XML document collecting fragments of text and noting the cursor position; both are stored in a new class for later use. The fragments of text come from an original text file, which is 'curated' by inhouse software to generate the XML file. Collected cursor position from the XML file (see below), reflect those same position in the original text file.

For example:

```
<paragraph><text index="0"/>The first char is index=0.
Then the next index position is <text index="59"/>here.
</paragraph>
```

Reflects the text (I've added labels to show the character index):

```
T(<-0)he first char is index=0.
Then the next index position is h(<-59)ere.
```

Apologies if these don't sum, it has been a long day.

Even in very complicated test XML files my code works. However, when I get my hands on their "real world" data the character position indices and number of characters between indices are all wrong.

Turns out that they performed a pre-processing step over their XML data and it has altered the carriage return and line feed encoding, thus no longer in synch with the original text file.

For example, the original text when viewed in Notepad++ appears as such:

```
This is a sentence. [CR][LF]
Followed by a second. [CR][LF]
Now we add some carriage returns [CR]
[CR][LF]
[CR]
[CR][LF]
Then another sentence and end of file
```

When I use their inhouse software to generate a test XML file the CR and LF reflects the original text as I had been briefed for.

Unfortunately, their pre-processing step over their non-test XML file has replaced all the CRs with `&#xd;` The above example would be:

```
&#xd;[LF]
&#xd;
&#xd;[LF]
```

The python XML parser is seeing `&#xd;` as a string literal and not as encoding. I've tried implementing fancy logic to write the file back out and correct for cursor positions, but it's getting chaotic.

Is there anyway of simply replacing the string literal `&#xd;` with it's true [CR] behaviour?

Comment: Is using `sed` an option?

Comment: I suspect not. The development environment is a remote Windows client. Access and installation of tools is strictly controlled.